# Second-hand alpine skiing equipment

Tags: equipment, skiing, maintenance

I'm a beginner skier and I want to buy a complete second hand equipment. Could you please tell me what to look for when choosing such an equipment to be sure that I get a still usable one?

Comment: I tried to be as clear as possible and to avoid asking for shopping recommendation. I did not asked for a store list or anything alike. I asked what to look for in terms of features, not brands, and not where to look for. In case I buy a second-hand equipment what are the things that I need to look for to be sure that the equipment is still usable? What are the common areas where ski equipment breaks?

Comment: I added the "maintenance" tag. From my perspective, it looks like a recommendation for specifically you, but thanks for clarifying that you are looking for a guideline as to how to choose second-hand equipment for beginners.

Comment: Yep, that's exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

As a beginner skier, I would recommend renting your equipment, particularly skis until you find the type and length you feel comfortable with.
You would want to start with a shorter ski until you feel comfortable with that length - nothing can deter a beginning skier faster that skis that are too long for them.
Once you are in a position to buy, many manufacturers offer 'demo days' where you can try out their different skis at no charge.
If you have progressed to a point where you're looking to buy, I would recommend starting with boots first as getting a proper fit can be difficult and most reputable ski shops will work with you to get the proper fit.
It wasn't until I started skiing that I found out I had flat feet, skiing for any length of time was extremely painful for me and I had to get orthotics for my feet. The shop that I purchased them from spent many hours shaving and trimming them until I was comfortable.
We always considered our boots the most important part of our equipment, when we flew somewhere new to ski, the boots always were 'carried on' the plane...if they lost your skis you could always rent another pair, but losing boots could be a disaster!